# Vagrant doesn't detect chef-solo unless re-installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, chef-solo

I am using Vagrant to test my Chef recipes in Amazon AWS, and I am encountering an irritating issue:

I initially assumed that Vagrant would install chef itself (as it does when using Virtual Box as the provider) but it seems that this needs to be done using the cloud-init script. However, even after I successfully installed the chef gem via cloud-init I was still getting the following error:

`The chef binary (either`chef-solo`or`chef-client`) was not found`

A quick google of this error suggested three probable causes:

- Chef had failed to install
- It had installed, but the directory was not in the $PATH environment variable
- It had installed and in the $PATH but with incorrect permissions

I logged in and double checked; chef-solo and chef-client were installed; The path variable for the user, sudo and root all included `/usr/local/bin` and permissions were all fine.

I managed to solve this problem by uninstalling and reinstalling the gem using `sudo gem install chef`. I don't understand why this should resolve the issue and it is a bit of a problem if I have to ssh into a test box and manually install the gem every time.

Does anyone have any suggestions why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't install `chef-client` via the gem.

Opscode recommends installing via their ["omnibus" installer](http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/).

A handy way to do this, via a Vagrant plugin is https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus.
`vagrant-omnibus` supports several provisioners, including `vagrant-aws`, and also supports a bunch of different distributions.

It's generally as easy as:

`$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus`
and adding a line of configuration to your `Vagrantfile`,

Answer (score -1):

Got the same problem here... for the time being I fixed it running:

```
vagrant ssh -c 'sudo ln -s /opt/chef/bin/* /usr/local/bin/'
```

But that is a crappy solution... I hope find something better as soon as I got some time.

Comment: BTW, please, somebody vote negative my own answer! is crappy :)